# Finding the Eigenvalues for big matrices

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

To start I have the following matrix (not so big)

I want to find the Eigenvalues in terms of kx and ky. I tried to use the classical

```
H=A-IdentityMatrix[Length[A]]*(Ene)
Solve[Det[H] == 0, Ene]
```

But for large matrices this will take so long.
The following matrix in the example (is Hermitian)

```
A={{0, 0, -0.03, -2.57 E^(I (-0.928571 kx - 0.371154 ky)) - 
   2.57 E^(I (kx/2 - (Sqrt[3] ky)/2)), 0, 0, -0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 
  0, -0.03, -2.57 E^(I (-0.142857 kx - 0.989743 ky)) - 
   2.57 E^(I (-(kx/2) - (Sqrt[3] ky)/2)), -0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {-0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {-2.57 E^(I (0.928571 kx + 0.371154 ky)) - 
   2.57 E^(I (-(kx/2) + (Sqrt[3] ky)/2)), -0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -0.03, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, -2.57 E^(I (0.142857 kx + 0.989743 ky)) - 
   2.57 E^(I (kx/2 + (Sqrt[3] ky)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.03, -0.03, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.03, 
  0}, {-0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, -0.03, 0, 0, 
  0, -2.57 E^(-I kx) - 2.57 E^(I (-0.785714 kx + 0.61859 ky)), 
  0, -2.57 E^(I (-0.142857 kx - 0.989743 ky)) - 
   2.57 E^(I (kx/2 - (Sqrt[3] ky)/2)), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -0.03, 
  0, 0, -2.57 E^(I kx) - 2.57 E^(I (0.785714 kx - 0.61859 ky)), 0, 0, 
  0, -2.57 E^(I (-0.928571 kx - 0.371154 ky)) - 
   2.57 E^(I (-(kx/2) - (Sqrt[3] ky)/2)), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -0.03, 0, 
  0, -0.03, 0, 0, 
  0, -2.57 E^(-I kx) - 2.57 E^(I (-0.785714 kx + 0.61859 ky)), 
  0, -0.03, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -2.57 E^(I (0.142857 kx + 0.989743 ky)) - 
   2.57 E^(I (-(kx/2) + (Sqrt[3] ky)/2)), 
  0, -2.57 E^(I kx) - 2.57 E^(I (0.785714 kx - 0.61859 ky)), 0, 
  0, -0.03, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -2.57 E^(I (0.928571 kx + 0.371154 ky)) - 
   2.57 E^(I (kx/2 + (Sqrt[3] ky)/2)), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -0.03, 0, 0, 0, -0.03, -0.03, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

As you may notice, this matrix has a lot of zeros. There is any method to condense these types of matrices to find the eigenvalues more quickly?

Comment: It looks like each row/column has at most 3 nonzero elements. If you could find a similarity transformation that would map it to a tridiagonal (banded) matrix, then it might be more feasible.

Comment: Since input has approximate numbers anyway, it might make sense to create an interpolating function in the variables `kx` and `ky`, provided the desired range of those variables is not too large.

Comment: I've tried ```CharacteristicPolynomial[H, Ene]``` and then ```Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[HAM, Ene] == 0, Ene]```but it is too slow too